# Micro Peli Case

Tags: storage

Two questions, albeit related ones. I'm currently looking for some storage solutions for when I'm out and about:

- a small waterproof case for my binaural mics (Soundman OKM II)
- a case to store my rycote portable audio recorder kit

I noticed that Peli Cases do a micro series and was wondering if anyone is using these for anything audio related? I think this could be the solution for the binaural kit.

Also, those of you who are using the rycote portable kit, baring in mind the lyre cradle part is a bit bulky and something you really don't want getting squashed out of shape, what are you using in terms of storage when you go from one place to the other? I've found a small Peli Case that may work, but does anyone have any other ideas.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I use a Pelican micro case for GoPro, charging accessories, and other stuff when sea kayaking.  So, as you might imagine, I don't $#&! around with water protection! :-) Works like a charm. My only complaint about them is that the rubber padding is also the o-ring seal, so you can't remove the padding without removing its waterproofness, unlike a standard Peli case (which has foam and a separate rubber o-ring).

They're all too small to carry something like a PCM-D50, though. I use a Pelican 1120 case for my PCM-D50. It's a small Pelican, not a micro Pelican, but it's the right size. The 1100 series surprisingly petite; the hardware is scaled down from the 1200-1700 series.

I've not messed with the Sofi-Cases either, but for large cylindrical objects, my suggestion would be waterproof dufflebags from [Watershed](http://www.drybags.com/). I keep my DSLR and a big, long lens in one, tucked in my kayak cockpit, for wildlife photography, and it's surprisingly bombproof. They would, if you get the right size, accommodate cylindrical bits like Rycote windshields.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @NoiseJockey Cheers for the input Nathan! I actually had the Peli 1120 in mind for the portable rycote kit so will prob get one and try it out. At worst, if it's not ideal I'll use it for my PCM D50 instead. Cheers for the tip on Watershed too. I've got a couple of HyperGear drybags but Watershed looks like a good range of gear.

Answer (score 1):

We have a couple of the smaller Pelican waterproof cases at work. One holds a small collection of lavalier microphones, and several others are used to hold 400 series Lectrosonics wireless systems. The cases we have will hold either one receiver, or two transmitters. They're aweseome little cases, and not TOO bulky. Good for keeping small items organized and protected.

As for the Rycote systems...yeah, we use Pelicans at work for those as well. I've been meaning to check these out to: http://www.alfacase.com/Softi-Case.html

First noticed them on Tim Prebble's blog. I wonder if they'll work for the full windshield systems. Their "[Combo Case](http://www.alfacase.com/Combo-Case.html)" is pretty interesting as well.

Comment: @Shaun Yeah I'm seriously considering getting one of the Alpha Case Mictube's to hold my shotgun in when I'm traveling. 

http://www.alfacase.com/MicTube.html

For my main rycote windshield I use a Satcom bag, as reviewed by Noise Jockey on his Portage series on Sonic Terrain. I'm really looking for something to hold my PCM-D50 portable rycote kit. Any ideas?


Comment: hmm...don't know. not really familiar with that particular kit. never seen an actual one in person.